Как расположить логотип левее?
подскажите пожалуйста как расположить блоки как на 1 картинке? 
У меня получается так и я не понимаю как переместить логотип левее.

код прилагаю:


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header,
.nav-main,
.nav-main__list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 56px;
  
  
}

header{
  width: 1512px;
}

.header__menu{
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-right: -120px;

}

.header__controls{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-right: 20px ;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 1372px;
}

header p{
  margin-left: 30px;  
}

.nav-main__list{
  gap: 33px;
}

.header__logo{
  z-index: 2;
  
}




body{
  /* font: 150 16px/18px; */

}

a{
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li{
  list-style-type: none;
  
}


.search {
  display: inline-flex;
  
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #EBEFEC;
}

.search-icon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  order: -1;
}

.search-field {
  width: 300px;
  border: 0; 
  background-color: #EBEFEC;
}

.search-field:focus {
  outline: none;
}





/* Описание меню */
.sidenav {
  height: 100%; /* 100% Full-height */
  width: 0; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
  top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff; /* Black*/
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
  padding-top: 60px; /* Place content 60px from the top */
  transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
}

/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #121613;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #12e435;
}

/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */
.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

/* Style page content - use this if you want to push the page content to the right when you open the side navigation */
#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}

#mySidenav{
  display:block;
  align-items: center;
}





 /* .header__search {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: #8f8f8f;
  color: #8f8f8f;
  width: 425px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  border-radius: 40px;
}
input {
  color: #8f8f8f;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  border: transparent;
}
i {
  color: #8f8f8f;
  margin-right: 20px;
} */


/* 

 form {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #EBEFEC;
}
input, button {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 42px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
button {
  height: 42px;
  width: 42px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button:before {
  content: "\f002";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #F9F0DA;
} */
  <header>
    <div class="header__controls">
    <span onclick="openNav()"><img src="/img/Head-menu.png" /></span>
    <img class="header__logo" src='img/header_logo.png' alt="Логотип">



    <div class="search">
      <input type="text" class="search-field" placeholder="Введите запрос">
      <img src="/img/Search.png" alt="" class="search-icon">
    </div>
 
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <a href="#">Товары</a>
      <a href="#">Услуги</a>
      <a href="#">Бренды</a>
    </div>

    <nav class="nav-main">
      <ul class="nav-main__list">
        <li class="nav-main__link nav-main__link__selected">
          <a href="#company">О компании</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-main__link">
          <a href="#carier">Карьера</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-main__link">
          <a href="#news">Новости</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-main__link">
          <a href="#contacts">Контакты</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <p>+7(499)707-71-53</p>
  </div>

  </header> 




Как вариант - гамбургер и лого поместить в один блок.

Oliver Patterson прав.

Блок header__controls у вас является flex-элементом c фиксированной шириной. Свойство justify-content: space-between говорит о том, что дочерние элементы внутри этого блока будут расположены так, чтобы промежутки между ними были одинаковы.
Логотип header__logo является таким дочерним элементом. Т.е. вы боретесь с эффектом, который сами сознательно создали.
Ладно, есть минимум 2 элементарных способа:

margin, например margin-left: -100px, или margin-right: auto.
translate, transform: translateX(-100px).

100px в данном случает условное значение - меняйте как угодно. Попробуйте все варианты, чтобы понять какой вам больше подходит.

Как по мне маржинами баловаться не стоит. Лучше сделать как Oliver Patterson написал - разделить блоки на два.

@ЕвгенийЛи в этом случае семантика и доступность пострадают.
